# A lot of inconsistent packages

Tags: python, macos, package, conda

When I have been trying to install new packages or update existing ones I am getting a message that the following packages are causing inconsistency:

```
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pywavelets==1.0.3=py37h1e5eb4f_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::odo==0.5.1=py_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::opentsne==0.3.8=py37heacc8b8_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pyproj==1.9.6=py37h01d97ff_1002
  - conda-forge/noarch::xarray==0.12.3=py_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::cufflinks-py==0.13.0=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::astropy==3.2.1=py37h01d97ff_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::orange3==3.22.0=py37h86efe34_0
  - defaults/osx-64::scikit-image==0.15.0=py37h0a44026_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::scipy==1.3.0=py37hab3da7d_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::scikit-learn==0.21.2=py37h2a6a0b8_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::imageio==2.5.0=py37_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::keras-preprocessing==1.0.9=py_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::msgpack-numpy==0.4.4.3=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::tensorflow-estimator==1.13.0=py37h24bf2e0_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::vaex-hdf5==0.5.2=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::quandl==3.4.6=py37_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pyarrow==0.14.1=py37he1943e6_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::tensorflow==1.13.1=py37_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::datashape==0.5.4=py_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::matplotlib-base==3.1.0=py37h3a684a6_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::cftime==1.0.3.4=py37h1e5eb4f_1001
  - conda-forge/osx-64::matplotlib==3.1.0=py37_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::pytest-arraydiff==0.3=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pygpu==0.7.6=py37h917ab60_1000
  - conda-forge/noarch::arviz==0.4.1=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::numexpr==2.6.9=py37h1702cab_1000
  - conda-forge/osx-64::h5py==2.9.0=nompi_py37h3d62f72_1103
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pytables==3.5.2=py37hc2baff1_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pyqtgraph==0.10.0=py_5
  - conda-forge/noarch::python-cufflinks==0.14.5=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::bottleneck==1.2.1=py37h917ab60_1001
  - conda-forge/osx-64::basemap==1.2.0=py37hd103db2_4
  - conda-forge/osx-64::pandas==0.25.0=py37h86efe34_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::vaex-arrow==0.3.5=py_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::vaex-viz==0.3.4=py_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::dask==2.2.0=py_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::sparse==0.7.0=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::tensorboard==1.13.1=py37_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pynndescent==0.3.0=py_0
  - defaults/osx-64::numpy==1.16.4=py37h926163e_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::hyperspy==1.4.1=py37h470a237_0
  - defaults/osx-64::spacy==2.0.12=py37h6440ff4_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pytest-astropy==0.5.0=py_0
  - defaults/osx-64::seaborn==0.9.0=py37_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::arrow-cpp==0.14.1=py37h43d7656_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::statsmodels==0.10.1=py37heacc8b8_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::parquet-cpp==1.5.1=2
  - conda-forge/osx-64::keras==2.2.4=py37_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::patsy==0.5.1=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::netcdf4==1.5.1.2=py37h58b02fa_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::keras-applications==1.0.7=py_1
  - conda-forge/osx-64::theano==1.0.4=py37h0a44026_1000
  - conda-forge/noarch::vaex-server==0.2.1=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::vaex-astro==0.5.0=py37_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::vaex==2.0.0=py_0
  - defaults/osx-64::bokeh==1.2.0=py37_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::fasttsne==0.2.16=py37hf8a1672_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::python-louvain==0.13=py_0
  - defaults/osx-64::blaze==0.11.3=py37_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::vaex-core==0.9.2=py37h86efe34_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::pymc3==3.7=py_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::numba==0.45.1=py37h86efe34_0
  - conda-forge/osx-64::thinc==6.10.3=py37h1702cab_1003
```

I read other posts on this subject which suggested updating the packages one by one.  I tried that for a few of them but that did not work and there are a lot of them to do.  Another suggested `conda clean --all` and then doing `conda update --all`.  When I tried to do the second part my computer sat at `Executing transaction` for days.  Literally it sat spinning at that stage for a couple of days before I canceled it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Maybe look into using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) or indirectly through [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: You are doing to need to give me more details.  I am not that advanced.

Comment: What are you trying to install/update?

Comment: I am getting it when I try to do any install or update.  The latest one was a Numpy update.  I got the inconsistency and then it stalled out (a / spins around forever).

Comment: More specifically, I would try updating the ones coming from **defaults** channel and try to switch them to **conda-forge** if possible. Also, make sure you have `conda config --set channel_priority true` and `conda-forge` has precedence in your `.condarc`. Generally, when using Conda you will be better off creating new environments for each project and avoid installing things in your **base** env.

Answer (score -1):

Following up from the comments, to install Numpy in a virtualenv:

```
$ pip install pipenv
$ pipenv install jupyter
$ pipenv install numpy
$ pipenv run python3
...
>>> import numpy as np
$ pipenv run jupyter notebook
```

This allows you to have multiple numpy versions installed throughout your system.

Comment: Will that work if I am using a notebook like Jupyter?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to run `jupyter notebook` too.